# chef fmw_domain cookbook "databag key parameter cannot be empty issue"

Tags: chef-infra

I am working on the cookbook released by oracle at https://github.com/oracle/chef-samples but facing issue in the fmw_domain cookbook as "databag key parameter cannot be empty".I am using chef solo to execute this cookbook.

hereby please find the node.json and solo.rb file

```
  {
  "run_list": ["recipe[fmw_jdk::install]",
               "recipe[fmw_jdk::rng_service]",
               "recipe[fmw_wls::setup]",
               "recipe[fmw_wls::install]",
               "recipe[fmw_domain::domain]"
              ],
  "fmw": {
    "java_home_dir": "/scratch/app/product/jdk1.8.0_102",
    "middleware_home_dir": "/scratch/app/product/fmw",
     "weblogic_home_dir":   "/scratch/app/product/fmw/wlserver",
      "orainst_dir":                    "/scratch/app/ora_home/",
      "user_home_dir":              "/scratch/app/ora_home/",
       "ora_inventory_dir":         "/scratch/app/ora_home/oraInventory",
       "tmp_dir":     "/scratch/app/ora_home/tmp",
       "version":             "12.1.3"
  },
  "fmw_jdk": {
    "source_file":         "/scratch/installables/jdk-8u102-linux-x64.tar.gz",
     "java" : {
      "jdk_version":"8",
      "oracle":{
        "accept_oracle_download_terms": "true"
      }
    }


  ,
  "fmw_wls": {
    "source_file":         "/scratch/installables/fmw_12.2.1.1.0_wls.jar"
  },

    "fmw_domain": {
     "id":                            "DEV_WLS1",
    "domains_dir":                "/scratch/app/product/fmw/user_projects/domains",
     "apps_dir":                  " /scratch/app/product/fmw/user_projects/applications",
    "nodemanager_listen_address": "10.184.152.137",
   "nodemanager_port":             5556,
   "nodemanager_secure_listener": "true"
  }

}
```

solo.rb

```
file_cache_path "scratch/ofssobp/Ankita/chef"

cookbook_path "/scratch/ofssobp/Ankita/chef/cookbook/"

json_attribs "/scratch/ofssobp/Ankita/node.json"

data_bag_path "/scratch/ofssobp/Ankita/data_bags"
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the code, the relevant line is `fail 'databag_key parameter cannot be empty' unless node['fmw_domain'].attribute?('databag_key')`. You need to set a `"databag_key"` attribute under the `"fmw_domain"` hash in your node data.

Comment: I added  "databag_key": "DEV_WLS1", in fmw_domains instead of "id" in node.json  but still the error persists.

Comment: What you see is what you get. Look at the stack trace, check the line that is raising the exception, and see what condition is causing it to fail. Errors don't lie :)